# Rainfall Frequency Analyses

Tags: atmosphere-modelling, precipitation

I have monthly precipitation data and would like to create the frequency curve for the 2, 5, 10, 100 year storms. I have access to NetStorm, STORMS 2000, CFA (from Environment Canada) and HEC-SSP.

The precipitation data is from the Caribbean so I can't use any predefined online databases. This isn't my area of expertise, I've just been given the task

Can anyone tell me how to go about creating these frequency curves for storms?
Thanks!!

Comment: why not just a professional software for this purpose - http://indico.ictp.it/event/a12165/session/21/contribution/16/material/0/0.pdf ?